# how to display a decimal number to 100 decimal places

Tags: python

I'm interested in displaying a decimal number to 100 decimal places.  Here is what I come up so far.  As can be seen, this is not quite what I wanted. ex. 1/3 should have 3's repeated to the end.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Python?

```
>>> x = 1./3
>>> "%.100f" % x
'0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> y = 1./7
>>> "%.100f" % y
'0.1428571428571428492126926812488818541169166564941406250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: `1./3` isn't stored as an infinite-precision decimal number,as you can see. You may want to look at the `decimal` module.

Comment: this isn't a display issue, this is just how floating-point arithmetic works.  [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
>>> decimal.Decimal(1) / decimal.Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is that floating point numbers have limited precision. If you want more than that, you need to use a different data type. I'd suggest investigating the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module, which can support arbitrarily large precisions.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = 1./3
>>> str(x).ljust(100, '0')
'0.33333333333300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: This neatly shows exactly why using floating-point is no use. It only stores abut 12 decimal digits of precision even though it can represent large numbers (in fact the larger the numbers get the larger the difference between successive floating-point numbers).

Answer (score -2):

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 10000000
print(decimal.Decimal(22) / decimal.Decimal(7))
```

Now you can increase the `prec` value and get to whatever decimal value you like.

Comment: How does this answer add anything beyond the existing answers? And why did you choose such a ridiculously large number for the precision?